# BASH Syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: bash

Any idea of what the problem could be?

My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
sleep 1
done
```

Saved it as .sh and ran bash file.sh

CentOS 6 32-bit

What is the issue? First time EVER using BASH, need it for a simple infinite loop on something.

Comment: Your code is correct and works for me using ubuntu. Is the code above an exact copy-past? What does `file file.sh` output?

Comment: What is the problem? Does it run but not work right? Does it not run at all? Does it give you some message? Do paisley ponies parade around your kitchen?

Comment: @twalberg: The error message (I presume) is in the title.

Comment: How did you type your code? Run `od -bc` on your source file and paste the output in your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right that there is an error message referenced in the title, but the posted code does not evoke that message, which renders the exact situation and question a bit unclear...

Comment: Try this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225055/while-read-line-do-cause-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-done-in-linux Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 51):

Run `cat -v file.sh`.

You most likely have a carriage return or no-break space in your file. `cat -v` will show them as `^M` and `M-BM-` or `M-` respectively. It will similarly show any other strange characters you might have gotten into your file.

Remove the Windows line breaks with

```
tr -d '\r' < file.sh > fixedfile.sh
```

Comment: Just to add to this - there's a bug in Notepad++ that continues to insert `\r\n` after the file has been converted to `\n`, if the conversion was done outside Notepad++.

Comment: This helped. I realized I had Windows line endings in the file and when I changed to Unix, the issue was solved.

Comment: For those who come across this question searching for the error message, other reasons that might cause the error messages are: ■
[empty loop body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11490760) ■
[forget `do`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70084373) ■
[missing `fi` inside loop body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10344508) ■

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same error on Cygwin; I did the following (one of them fixed it):

1. Converted `TABS` to `SPACES`
2. ran `dos2unix` on the `.(ba)sh` file

Comment: Converting tabs to spaces shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I would assume the line ending in DOS were the reason for the error

Comment: The only solution that worked. I used "od -a" but that one didn't find characters.

Answer (score 7):

What is the error you're getting?

```
$ bash file.sh
test.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If you get that error, you may have bad line endings. Unix uses `<LF>` at the end of the file while Windows uses `<CR><LF>`. That `<CR>` character gets interpreted as a character.

You can use `od -a test.sh` to see the *invisible* characters in the file.

```
$ od -a test.sh
0000000    #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  cr  nl   #  sp  cr
0000020   nl   w   h   i   l   e  sp   :  cr  nl   d   o  cr  nl  sp  sp
0000040   sp  sp   e   c   h   o  sp   "   P   r   e   s   s  sp   [   C
0000060    T   R   L   +   C   ]  sp   t   o  sp   s   t   o   p   "  cr
0000100   nl  sp  sp  sp  sp   s   l   e   e   p  sp   1  cr  nl   d   o
0000120    n   e  cr  nl                                                
0000124
```

The `sp` stands for space, the `ht` stands for tab, the `cr` stands for `<CR>` and the `nl` stands for `<LF>`. Note that all of the lines end with `cr` followed by a `nl` character.

You can also use `cat -v test.sh` if your `cat` command takes the `-v` parameter.

If you have `dos2unix` on your box, you can use that command to fix your file:

```
$ dos2unix test.sh
```

Comment: OD is a lifesaver for seeing invisible characters.

Answer (score 6):

There's a way you can get this problem without having mixed newline problems (at least, in my shell, which is GNU bash v4.3.30):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# foo.sh

function foo() {
    echo "I am quoting a thing `$1' inside a function."
}

while [ "$input" != "y" ]; do
    read -p "Hit `y' to continue: " -n 1 input
    echo
done

foo "What could possibly go wrong?"
```

```
$ ./foo.sh
./foo.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./foo.sh: line 11: `done'
```

This is because bash expands backticks inside double-quoted strings (see the bash manual on [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)), and before finding a matching backtick, will interpret any additional double quotes as part of the command substitution:

```
$ echo "Command substitution happens inside double-quoted strings: `ls`"
Command substitution happens inside double-quoted strings: foo.sh
$ echo "..even with double quotes: `grep -E "^foo|wrong" foo.sh`"
..even with double quotes: foo "What could possibly go wrong?"
```

You can get around this by escaping the backticks in your string with a backslash, or by using a single-quoted string.

I'm not really sure why this only gives the one error message, but I think it has to do with the function definition:

```
#!/bin/bash
# a.sh

function a() {
    echo "Thing's `quoted'"
}
a
while true; do
    echo "Other `quote'"
done
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# b.sh

echo "Thing's `quoted'"
while true; do
    echo "Other `quote'"
done
```

```
$ ./a.sh
./a.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./a.sh: line 10: `done'
$ ./b.sh
./b.sh: command substitution: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./b.sh: command substitution: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Thing's quote'
./b.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./b.sh: line 7: `done'
```

Comment: I know this doesn't strictly answer the question asked, but since this is the first google result for "bash syntax error near unexpected token done", I imagine this will still be useful to some people.

Comment: this helped me realize I should replace double quotes `"` with single quotes `'` to avoid bash doing something with the quoted exclamation marks `echo "!! ok"` --> `echo '!! ok'`

Comment: why would I be experiencing this exact same problem but I don't have any backticks inside double-quotes? I have this for loop:     for (( i=1; i<=FULL_SIZE_CHUNKS; i++ ));
    do
        send_chunk ${i} '{"P":"1"}'

        SKIP=$(( READ_COUNT + SKIP ))
        READ_COUNT=$(( CHUNK_SIZE - 34 ))
    done

Answer (score 4):

Might help someone else : I encountered the same kind of issues while I had done some "copy-paste" from a side Microsoft Word document, where I took notes, to my shell script(s).

Re-writing, manually, the exact same code in the script just solved this.

It was quite un-understandable at first, I think Word's hidden characters and/or formatting were the issue. Obvious but not see-able ... I lost about one hour on this (I'm no shell expert, as you might guess ...)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this error happens because of unexpected CR characters in file, usually because the file was generated on a Windows system which uses CR line endings. You can fix this by running `os2unix` or `tr`, for example:

> tr -d '\015' < yourscript.sh > newscript.sh

This removes any CR characters from the file.

Answer (score 2):

**Open new file named** `foobar`

```
nano -w foobar
```

**Input script**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while [ 0 = 0 ]; do
   echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
   sleep 1
 done;
```

**Exit and save**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Set script executable and run**

```
chmod +x foobar
./foobar
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all... (what's the problem?)

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problems just now and these are two separate instances and solutions that worked for me:

**Case 1.** Basically, **had a space after the last command** within my *newline-separated* for-loop, eg. (imagining that `|` here represents the carat in a text editor showing where you are writing), this is what I saw when clicking around the end of the line of the last command in the loop:

```sh
for f in $pathToFiles
do
   $stuff |
done
```

Notice the space before before the carat (so far as I know, this is something `cat` has no option do display visually (one way you *could* test is with something like `od -bc yourscript.sh`)). Changing the code to

```sh
for f in $pathToFiles
do
   $stuff| <--- notice the carat shows no ending space before the newline
done
```

fixed the problem.

**Case 2.** Was using a pseudo try-catch block for the for-loop (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010339/8236733) like

```
{
for f in $pathToFiles
do
   { $stuff } || { echo "Failed to complete stuff"; exit 255; }
done
} || { echo "Failed to complete loop"; exit 255; }
```

and apparently bash did not like the nested `{}`s. Changing to

```
{
for f in $pathToFiles
do
   $stuff
done
} || { echo "Failed to complete loop"; exit 255; }
```

fixed the problem in this case. If anyone can further explain either of these cases, please let me know more about them in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but solved.

I removed the following line in .bashrc

```
alias do="docker.exe" # this line caused the problem
```

I use WSL(windows subsystem for linux)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, what was causing the problem was an `if else` statement. After re-writing the conditions, the error 'near done' got away.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code in any linux environment then you won't face this problem. If edit in windows 
notepad any space take it as ^M.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue as above, and took me the whole day to discover that it doesn't like my newline approach. Instead I reused the same code with semi-colon approach instead.
For example my initial code using the newline (which threw the same error as yours):

```
Y=1
while test "$Y" -le "20"
do
        echo "Number $Y"
        Y=$[Y+1]
done
```

And using code with semicolon approach with worked wonder:

```
Y=1 ; while test "$Y" -le "20"; do echo "Number $Y"; Y=$[Y+1] ; done
```

I notice the same problem occurs for other commands as well using the newline approach, so I think I am gonna stick to using semicolon for my future code.

Comment: If the newlines are the problem, you should probably `dos2unix` the file because it contains Windows newlines.

Answer (score 0):

For me you had to have it do something between the do and done.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Endless Loop, to STOP press ctrl C or ctrl Z"

for ((; ;))
do

done
echo "Loop Ended"
```

gave me the error, but

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Endless Loop, to STOP press ctrl C or ctrl Z"

for ((; ;))
do
     sleep 1
done
echo "Loop Ended"
```

fixed it.