# Get row count from all tables in hive

Tags: hql, hive

How can I get row count from all tables using hive? I am interested in the database name, table name and row count

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45304801/7043815) hope it helps!!

Answer (score 29):

You will need to do a

```
select count(*) from table
```

for all tables.

To automate this, you can make a small bash script and some bash commands.
First run

```
$hive -e 'show tables' | tee tables.txt
```

This stores all tables in the database in a text file tables.txt

Create a bash file (count_tables.sh) with the following contents.

```
while read line
do
 echo "$line "
 eval "hive -e 'select count(*) from $line'"
done
```

Now run the following commands.

```
$chmod +x count_tables.sh
$./count_tables.sh < tables.txt > counts.txt
```

This creates a text file(counts.txt) with the counts of all the tables in the database

Comment: when I run this after an `INSERT INTO TABLE table SELECT row FROM another_table` I get only the number of rows added and not the total number of rows in table, do you how I can always get the total number of rows?

Comment: @Mukul the output is +-----Table-----+.... with lines starting and ending with | .  Any way to grab just the table name?

Answer (score 4):

A much faster way to get approximate count of all rows in a table is to run explain on the table. In one of the explain clauses, it shows row counts like below:

`TableScan [TS_0] (rows=224910 width=78)`

The benefit is that you are not actually spending cluster resources to get that information.

---

The HQL command is `explain select * from table_name;` but when not optimized **not shows rows** in the TableScan.

Comment: what is "run explain on the table" is that `explain table db.table;`? Because that's not valid.

Answer (score 1):

`select count(*) from table`

I think there is no more efficient way.

Comment: How can this be automated for all tables in a database. I am actually interested in a feature similar to information_schema.tables like feature in hive which would enlist record count in all tables in a database using HQL. Any thoughts

Comment: Any such feature in derby. What is the database name of the metastore by default?

Comment: Derby or MySQL just store meta info of table, that is the schema. In hive, schema of table just define a way to process data in hdfs. When you load data in hive, hive just put file in hdfs and update hdfs location in metastore. There is no counter in metastore.

Comment: This helps. Thank you. What can be done when such an audit feature is required to understand how many rows were loaded in all tables across databases. I would not like to issue several count * and would like to keep that as the last option.

Comment: when I run this after an `INSERT INTO TABLE table SELECT row FROM another_table` I get only the number of rows added and not the total number of rows in table, do you how I can always get the total number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the statistics on the table by using Hive ANALAYZE command. Hive cost based optimizer makes use of these statistics to create optimal execution plan.

Below is the example of computing statistics on Hive tables:

```
hive> ANALYZE TABLE stud COMPUTE STATISTICS;
 Query ID = impadmin_20171115185549_a73662c3-5332-42c9-bb42-d8ccf21b7221
 Total jobs = 1
 Launching Job 1 out of 1
 …
 Table training_db.stud stats: [numFiles=5, numRows=5, totalSize=50, rawDataSize=45]
 OK
 Time taken: 8.202 seconds
```

Links:
http://dwgeek.com/apache-hive-explain-command-example.html/

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the database in the same command and separate with `;`.

```
hive -e 'use myDatabase;show tables'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this guys to automate-- put in shell after that run bash filename.sh

hive -e 'select count(distinct fieldid) from table1 where extracttimestamp<'2018-04-26'' > sample.out

hive -e 'select count(distinct fieldid) from table2 where day='26'' > sample.out

lc=`cat sample.out | uniq | wc -l`
if [ $lc -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "PASS"
else
 echo "FAIL"
fi

Answer (score 0):

How do I mention the specific database that it needs to refer in below snippet:

```
while read line
do
 echo "$line "
 eval "hive -e 'select count(*) from $line'"
done
```

Comment: By the way, I assume that this is an answer starting off with a rethoric question. If you are asking this, please turn it instead into a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I wrote that uses python:

```
import os
dictTabCnt={}

print("=====Finding Tables=====")
tableList = os.popen("hive --outputformat=dsv --showHeader=false -e \"use [YOUR DB HERE]; show tables;\"").read().split('\n')

print("=====Finding Table Counts=====")
for i in tableList:
    if i <> '':
        strTemp = os.popen("hive --outputformat=dsv --showHeader=false -e \"use [YOUR DB HERE]; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {}\"".format(i)).read()
        dictTabCnt[i] = strTemp

print("=====Table Counts=====")
for table,cnt in dictTabCnt.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(table,cnt))
```

Comment: depends on `select count(*) from table`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@mukul_gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112010/mukul-gupta) for providing shell script.

how ever we are encounting below error for the same

"**bash syntax error near unexpected token done**"

Solution for this at below link

[BASH Syntax error near unexpected token 'done'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367708/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-done)

Also if any one need how to select DB Name

```
$hive -e 'use databasename;show tables' | tee tables.txt
```

for passing db name in select statement, give DB name in tableslist file itself.