# syntax error near unexpected token 'done'?

Tags: bash, shell

```
while :; echo 'wtf'; done;
```

> line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

well i certainly have no idea what's wrong with this line. I don't think is the `while :` part, it's supposed to be a while true loop.

Comment: Your code misses the "do" : `while :; do echo "wtf"; done;`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367108/what-does-while-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `while` allows multiple commands to be executed to test the condition.  Those commands are separated from the commands which are conditionally executed by the keyword `do`.  Consider the line:

```
while true; echo 'wtf'; echo foo; do echo bar; done
```

The "do" is essential.  In the above, 3 commands are unconditionally executed.  If `echo foo` succeeds, then `echo bar` will be executed and the loop repeats.  If `echo foo` fails, the loop terminates.  If `done` is seen before `do`, it is a syntax error.